# Attribute cf-hash not allowed on element script at this point in validator W3

Tags: html, w3c-validation

When I check my website in the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), I get this error: "Attribute cf-hash not allowed on element script at this point".

This is my site source code:

```
<a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#71121003141403311a140210051e5f121e1c" itemprop="email" class="last-link"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="2b484a594e4e596b404e584a5f4405484446">[email&#160;protected]</span><script cf-hash='f9e31' type="text/javascript">,
```

Comment: Hey Nathan, CloudFlare have acknowledged this is an issue caused by their email obfuscation solution and have advised me to switch it off until they have fixed it. http://i.imgur.com/4j0DZDG.png

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you everything you need to know: the `script` element can’t have a `cf-hash` attribute. The allowed attributes are listed in the [specification of the `script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

If you need a custom attribute, use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) (just like you use them on the `a` element):

```
<script data-cf-hash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Yup. But the cf-hash attribute is added by Cloudflare's DNS system and usually due to their email protection feature. I'll tweet them and hopefuly bring attention to this issue.

Comment: Cloudflare have acknowledged the problem and advised me to switch off email obfuscation until they've fixed it, which might take some time. http://i.imgur.com/4j0DZDG.png